# Installation of Caffe in COLAB

Tags: deep-learning, windows-10, caffe, google-colaboratory

I want to use caffe in Google colab for experiment purpose, and my understanding is that i need to setup and install caffe every time i open python notebook in every runtime. This is very hard and time consuming because caffe takes lot of time to install and sometimes fails to install.

So i wanted to know if i am doing something wrong or is that the way how colab runtime works?

I would like to know of any other alternative platform for free which i can use if i need to setup caffe every time i use colab. I want to use Alex net pre tained caffe model

And moreover i wasted last 2 complete days setting up caffe locally on windows 10 machine, which by the way still not working, i am really getting sick of this caffe.

Answer (score 5):

On Colab you can install the pre-compiled Caffe using

```
!apt install caffe-cpu
```

For GPU runtime, you can use `caffe-cuda` as well.

See [instruction here](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/install_apt.html).

Comment: I can NOT find convert_mnist_data.bin in all paths of caffe,could you helo me?Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> is that the way how colab runtime works?

Yes it is!
To have persistent data you have to save your notebook to your drive:
`File/Save a copy in Drive`

Comment: I do save it in drive and launch new runtime using same file, but my question to all the caffe users is that, do you install and setup caffe everytime you use it for your deeplearning purpose? I follow the installation steps from "https://habrahabr.info/administration/cloud-computing/2397-build-caffe-in-google-colaboratory-a-free-video-card-in-the-cloud.html" blog post. So does all caffe users execute all the steps mentioned to setup caffe?